# How to $lookup entries from array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have three collections, Posts, Languages and Translations. And the structure looks like this:

```
Post: {
    id: ObjectID
    title: String,
    translated_versions: ObjectID
}

TranslatedVersion: {
    id: ObjectID
    translations: Translation[]
}

// Just an object structure in TranslatedVersion.translations, not collection
Translation: {
    post: ObjectID
    language: ObjectID
}

Language {
    id: ObjectID
    name: String
}
```

What I want to do is to get entry from translated versions collections, put it into my post and then for every entry in TranslatedVersion.translation I want to get post and language objects, so it will look like this:

```
Post {
    title: "Test title",
    translated_versions: {
        id: 'some-id',
        tranlations: [
            Translation {
                language: {
                    id: 'some-id',
                    name: 'Turkish'
                },
                post: {
                    id: 'some-id'
                    title: 'Turkish post'
                }
            },
            Translation {
                language: {
                    id: 'some-id',
                    name: 'English'
                },
                post: {
                    id: 'some-id',
                    title: 'English post'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using Golang and I tried to do it this way (sorry lots of lines of code):

```
    lookup_translations_group := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$lookup", Value: bson.D{
                {
                    Key: "from", Value: Models.Translation,
                },
                {
                    Key: "localField", Value: "translations_group_id",
                },
                {
                    Key: "foreignField", Value: "_id",
                },
                {
                    Key: "as", Value: "translations",
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

```
    unwind_translations_group := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$unwind", Value: bson.D{
                {
                    Key: "path", Value: "$translations",
                },
                {
                    Key: "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", Value: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

```
    lookup_translations_posts := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$lookup", Value: bson.D{
                {
                    Key: "from", Value: Models.Post,
                },
                {
                    Key: "localField", Value: "translations.translations.post",
                },
                {
                    Key: "foreignField", Value: "_id",
                },
                {
                    Key: "as", Value: "translations.translations.post",
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Then I run mongo.Pipeline and what I get is an object with "post" field which is an array with my translated posts:

[image]

So obviously I am doing something wrong here :( I assume I need to add another pipeline in lookup_translations_group stage, but I have no idea how to it correctly.

upd2:
Even more complex examples:

```
db.posts.insertMany([
   { "_id" : 1, "title": "English post", language: 1, category: 1, "translations": 1, },
   { "_id" : 2, "title": "Turkish post", langauge: 2, category: 1, "translations": 1, },
   { "_id" : 2, "title": "Finnish post", language: 3, category: 1, "translations": 1, },
])

db.languages.insertMany([
   { "_id" : 1, "name": "English", },
   { "_id" : 2, "name": "Turkish", },
   { "_id" : 3, "name": "Finnish", },
])

db.translations.insert({
   "_id" : 1, 
   translations: [
      { language: 1, post: 1 },
      { language: 2, post: 2 },
      { language: 3, post: 3 },
   ] 
})

db.categories.insert({
   "_id" : 1, 
   "name": "Random category"
})
```

Result that I want:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "title": "English post",
   "language": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "English"
   },
   "category": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Random category"
   },
   "translations": {
      "_id": 1,
      translations: [
         {
            "language": {
               "_id": 1,
               "name": "English"
            },
            "post": {
               "_id": 1,
               "title": "English post",
               "category": {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "name": "Random category"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "language": {
               "_id": 2,
               "name": "Turkish"
            },
            "post": {
               "_id": 2,
               "title": "Turkish post",
               "category": {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "name": "Random category"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "language": {
               "_id": 3,
               "name": "Finnish"
            },
            "post": {
               "_id": 3,
               "title": "Finnish post",
               "category": {
                  "_id": 1,
                  "name": "Random category"
               }
            }
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the sample documents to create the requested result

Comment: @nimrodserok I did. What exactly was unclear?

Comment: You provided the schemas, not the documents themselves. In order to play with the data to get the result you want we need the sample documents needed to create this expected result

Comment: @nimrodserok added now. Tell me please if it helps or if you need any other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
db.translations.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: 1}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "translations.post",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "posts"
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "languages",
      localField: "posts.language",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "translations"
  }},
  {$project: {
      data: {$map: {
          input: "$posts",
          in: {
            post: {title: "$$this.title", _id: "$$this._id"},
            language: {$arrayElemAt: [
                "$translations",
                {$indexOfArray: ["$translations._id", "$$this._id"]}
            ]}
          }
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [
          {$first: {$filter: {input: "$data", cond: {$eq: ["$$this.post._id", "$_id"]}}}},
          {translations: {
              _id: "$_id",
              translations: {
                $filter: {input: "$data", cond: {$ne: ["$$this.post._id", "$_id"]}}
              }
          }}
      ]}
  }},
  {$project: {_id: "$post._id", title: "$post.title", language: 1, translations: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdzlIW-yfTz)

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I need. But is that supposed to be that complicated? 

Comment: Speaking of which. I just thought what if I need to aggregate something to posts inside of translations array, like category or something  It would be hell of a pipeline

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: BTW, according to your current example, I don't see the benefit in maintaining a `languages` collection. Unless it holds more information, it is redundant.

Comment: updated original post (added "category" field)

Comment: Again, you are trying to preform a calculation over 4 different collection. It is possible but it is not a good use for mongodb and not considered as best practice. In this example I would use only `posts` and `translations` and integrate the other 2 into them. This will make the query much simpler.